# How I do compare objects in a ArrayList against each other in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entities:
 `Individual` and `TaxPayer` in the following way:

```
public class Individual {     
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   @OneToOne
   private TaxPayer taxpayer;
   // other fields
}
```

and:

```
public class TaxPayer {
   private String phoneNumber;
   private String stateTin;//unique code
   private String email;
   //other fields
}
```

I have a list of individuals like so:

```
List<Individual> individualList = getAllIndividualsWithDuplicatePhonenumber();
```

I want to compare the firstName and lastName of an individual with other individuals in the list so that I will get a list of all individuals where the **firstName and lastName matches with the other individual's firstName and lastName** OR **firstName of the individual matches the lastName of the other individual and lastName of the individual matches the firstName of the other individual**
PS: TaxPayer entity is eager-fetched on Individual so I can access the attributes of TaxPayer by doing `individual.getTaxPayer().getPhoneNumber();`

Comment: Have Individual implement the hashCode, equals methods and Comparable interface.  Put your logic in those methods.

Comment: Please can you help me write the logic? @duffymo

Comment: Seems odd: you are willing to tolerate code where users invert the first and last name.

Answer (score 2):

You should read [Joshua Bloch's Effective Java chapter 3](https://www.slideshare.net/MukkamalaKamal/joshua-bloch-effect-java-chapter-3) to learn how to override `equals` and `hashCode`.

Try this:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) return true;
    if (other == null || other.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
    Individual individual = (Individual) other;
    return ((this.getFirstName().equals(individual.getFirstName() && this.getLastName().equals(individual.lastName()) || 
        (this.getFirstName().equals(individual.getLastName() && this.getLastName().equals(individual.getFirstName())) 
}
```

Comment: Using your equals() method, If I stream individualList to get duplicate individual like: individualList.stream().filter(individual -> //what to write here) .collect(Collectors.toList())
how do I apply the equals() method in my stream.

Comment: Call Individual::equals and include or exclude objects according to your requirements.